# How to apply colors for expanded and collapsed toggle in angular 2

Tags: angular, toggle, accordion

[image]Below is my code for toggle functionality I want to apply colors like grey color when it is in expanded state and black color when it is in collapsed state. How do i achieve this?

```
    <div *ngFor="let point of points; let i = index">
      <ul class="list-group bottom-30">
        <li class="list-group-item" style="margin-top: 15px;" (click)="toggle[i] = !toggle[i]">
          {{points.description}}
          <i class="fa" style="float:right" [ngClass]="{'fa-plus': toggle[i], 'fa-minus': !toggle[i]}" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Using a class along with `[ng-class]` would be one way of doing it

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are using [ngClass] correctly, I would suggest just passing it a string instead.

I would suggest using CSS and calling a function with `[NgClass]` [ref](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)

HTML

```
<li 
  class="list-group-item" 
  style="margin-top: 15px;" 
  (click)="toggle[i] = !toggle[i]"
>
  {{points.description}}
  <i 
    class="fa" 
    style="float:right" 
    [ngClass]="getClass(toggle[i])" 
    aria-hidden="true"
  ></i>
</li>
```

TS

```
public toggle = {};

public getClass(toggle) {
    return toggle ? 'fa-plus toggled' : 'fa-minus someOtherClass';
}
```

CSS

```
.toggled {
    color: red;
 }
```

Another possibility would be to use `ngStyle` [ref](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle)

```
<i [ngStyle]="{'color.red': !toggled}"></i>
```

Here is the stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-evm3bu

EDIT: updated with some details.

Comment: What is your toggle function doing?

Comment: toggle function expands and collapses

Comment: ok i dont want to change the color of icon.Instead i want to change the color of li part completely.Icon color wil not change

Comment: what exactly do you mean by 'li part'? you just need to change the css, accordingly.

Comment: li part is nothing but the top portion as shown in the attached image. the portion with white color.

Comment: I updated the stackblitz with the opening/closing container: https://angular-evm3bu.stackblitz.io